# Interacting with a running interactive console program from a different process

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, background-process

I have a console program with an interactive shell, similar to say, the Python interactive shell.  Is there an easy way to start this interactive program A and then use another program B to run A?  I want to do something like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/A&
$ #find PID of A somehow
$ somecommand "PID of A" "input string to send to A"
output string from A
$
```

What kind of "somecommand" could do this?  Is this what "expect" is supposed to facilitate?  I read the `expect` man page but still have no idea what it does.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. How you write it, I expect `somecommand` to be a command belonging to your interactive shell A. So how would a different program B be defined? (sure this is not an XY problem?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`expect` is for a different purpose.  It runs commands on a captive program.  You, by contrast, are asking for a way to send commands to a process already running in the background.

As a *bare-bones* minimal example of what you want, let's create a FIFO:

```
$ mkfifo in
```

A FIFO is a special file that one process can write to while a different process reads from it.  Let's create a process to read from our FIFO file `in`:

```
$ python <in &
[1] 3264
```

Now, let's send `python` a command to run from the current shell:

```
$ echo "print 1+2" >in
$ 3
```

The output from `python` is `3` and appears here on stdout.  If we had redirected python's stdout, it could be sent elsewhere.

#### What `expect` does

`expect` allows you to automate interaction with a captive command.  As an example of what `expect` can do, create a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
spawn python
expect ">>>"
send "print 1+2\r"
expect ">>>"
```

Then, run this file with `expect`:

```
$ expect myfile
spawn python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 1+2
3
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was exactly what I was wondering.  It's too bad man pages can't be as well written as your comment!

Comment: this was very helpful, however some interactive prompts would need a `tail -f in | python &`-like syntax

Comment: @Blauhirn Interesting.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: @John1024 yes: try your python example yourself. the `print` command can be executed only once, the python shell stops after that. but concerning my previous comment: you'd need that for `wish`: while `wish <in &` does work, it only accepts the first interaction (echo, cat instance). I needed to write `tail -f in |wish &`  for it to handle multiple echos. -thanks

Comment: Yes, I see that.  On the other hand, `tail -f in | python` is not working for me at all: the python process hangs without ever responding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the sort of thing you can do with expect, where your expect script is your program B. Basically, it expects some string (maybe a command prompt) and then sends a response.

Check out autoexpect which will help generate your expect script by recording a session. If you play with it a bit and inspect its output, you will get a better idea of how it works.